# Rock paper scissor program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {  
char c_ch, p_ch;// c_ch = computer choice  ---- p_ch = player choice  
cin >> p_ch;  
c_ch = rand() % 3 + 1;  
switch (c_ch) {  
    case 1:  
        c_ch = "rock"; 
        break;  
    case 2:  
        c_ch = "paper";
        break;  
    case 3:  
        c_ch = "scissor";
        break;  
    default:  
        break;
}  
if (c_ch == "rock" && p_ch == "paper") cout << "p win";  
else if (c_ch == "rock" && p_ch == "scissor") cout << "c win";  
else if (c_ch == "paper" && p_ch == "rock") cout << "c win";  
else if (c_ch == "paper" && p_ch == "scissor") cout << "p win";  
else if (c_ch == "scissor" && p_ch == "paper") cout << "c win";  
else if (c_ch == "scissor" && p_ch == "rock") cout << "p win";  
return 0;  
}

 error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

What do i do?I got this error comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior.
So, i used rand() to pick a number from 1 to 3 , 1 beeing rock 2 paper and 3 scissor, and more down below at the if statements i compared them with the player`s choice.

Comment: For player's choice are they going to type in a whole word, like "rock" - if so, that won't fit i a single `char`

Comment: -6 is really harsh for a compilable example. Please don't downvote on grounds of obviousness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have highlighted the basic problems below.  You can probably change your code to use better idioms but for the following should be sufficient for now.

You are comparing characters with `const char*` values, this is ill formed code.  String literals in C++ of the form `"__characters__"` are of the type `const char*`, and it does not mean anything to compare these values to characters, a character is a plain and simple character, not a string.

Put an `#include <string>` at the top of your program and change the types of `c_ch` and `p_ch` to be `std::string`s and not `char`s

Also use an int to assign the `rand()` value, and not `c_ch`

Comment: In function ‘int main()’:
    error: switch quantity not an integer switch (c_ch) { it worked but now i got this

Comment: Use an `int` to assign the `rand()` value, and not `c_ch`

Comment: It got compiled now but when  player choice is paper nothing is showed and when is scissor always player wins, i think that  it`s something wrong with the rand().

Comment: Add a `std::srand(time(0));` at the top of main and add `#include <ctime>` at the top of your `.cpp` file

Answer (score 0):

Yuck. Strings like `"rock"` &c. are for humans, not computers; you only need strings when outputting information to or reading in data from users.

Your specific problem is due to your attempting to convert `const char[]` literals to `char` values and your compiler is attempting to decay the literals to `const char*` before giving up.

The easiest fix is to work with an `int` type, and have a convention for rock, paper, scissors being 0, 1, and 2. To get started, accept that from the user.

Once you have that working, consider graduating to accepting a `std::string` from the user. You can then convert that to 0, 1, and 2 using an `if` block:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
// ToDo - map input to a number.
```

Then consider using an `enum` but then you complicate the random number drawings.